# Customize style of MessageDialog

Tags: xaml, uwp, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal, messagedialog

I'm using the [`DisplayAlert()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayAlert/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String/) method in Xamarin.Forms. [Internally](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/0cc2fd2b6742a29fedc03de942801cc14ff6b499/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/Platform.cs#L746) it uses [`MessageDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208674).

How can I change the style of the ok and cancel button on different events like `PointerOver`, `Pressed`, and so on?

[Here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/213399/#Comment_213399) one does implement it's own `ContentDialog` with the according [style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299120.aspx). Other try to override some brushes, with the disadvantage that other things are changed too.

Has anyone got it managed to override the style/control template only for a `MessageDialog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, apart from the displayed text and buttons you can't customize a `MessageDialog` at all.

I think the simplest solution would be to create your own `IDialogService`, that would be an interface in the `PCL` with a `DisplayDialog` method. This method would have the same parameters as the `Xamarin.Forms` `DisplayAlert` method.

Now you would provide an implementation of this interface on each platform. In case of Android and iOS I suppose you want to keep the current behavior intact, so the implementation of the `DisplayDialog` method could just call Xamarin's `DisplayAlert` directly, just passing the arguments.

In case of Windows, you could then display your custom `ContentDialog`.

An example of writing platform specific services is [available in Xamarin Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/).